# Add dynamically fields to form - what with validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form where user can add dynamically fields 'Name' to my form, I use knockoutjs to add fields dynamically - but in that case validation works wrong - for example when 'Name' is required if I don't fill one of many 'Name' fields then I see validation message on each field:

[image]

I thought that knockoutjs can help me in that case but it helps only in adding fields dynamically. Now I use validation attributes in my model:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Should I add separate validation in javascriptin in view if I add fields dynamically?**

This is my view with knockoutjs:

```
@model Knockout.Models.Person

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <!-- ko foreach: positions -->
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { data_bind = "value: name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <button data-bind="click: addPosition">Add one</button>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = createViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });

    function createViewModel() {
        var createPosition = function () {
            return {
                name: ko.observable()
            };
        };

        var addPosition = function () {
            positions.push(createPosition());
        };

        var positions = ko.observableArray([createPosition()]);

        return {
            positions: positions,
            addPosition: addPosition
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery.validate.js?

Comment: Yes, I am. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

use this function to add required Field validation to dynamically created control

pass element id to function
e.g.

```
setRequiredFieldValidation('#YourCreatedElementID')
```

function

```
function setRequiredFieldValidation(element) {
    var $PropElement = $(element).filter(':not(:hidden)');
    if ($PropElement.length > 0 && $PropElement[0].getAttribute('data-val-required') == null) {
        var $label = $('label[for=\'' + $PropElement[0].id + '\']');
        if ($label.length > 0) {
            $label.prepend('<span class=\'mandatory\' >*</span>') ///For ADA Compliance... To add the asterix before the required element...
            var errorMessage = "";
            if ($PropElement.attr("val-label-text"))
                errorMessage =  $PropElement.attr("val-label-text") + " is required.";
            else
                errorMessage = $label.text().replace(/^\*/, '') + " is required.";
            $PropElement.attr('data-val-required', errorMessage); ///To set the error message and add the JQuery UnObtrusive Required field validation...
            ///This is for adding the data-val attribute to the dynamically created required fields...
            if (!$PropElement.attr('data-val')) {
                $PropElement.attr('data-val', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```